# GET image 404 (Not Found)

Tags: image, reactjs, http-status-code-404

For my web app ,Some of the images keep giving me 404, which cannot be found. But I can see them on my local server, and they are uploaded to github when I push the code. 
for example, none of the images can be found in this page. http://kyloxue.design/#/Project6?_k=gxpciy
I made sure that the first image is available with the correct url: https://github.com/alfance/alfance.github.io/blob/master/media/img/dme/all1.png
but most of the images in this page work fine. http://kyloxue.design/#/Project1?_k=nbyvg2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are case sensitive. For example, you have an image referencing:

http://kyloxue.design/media/img/DME/all1.png

Change that to http://kyloxue.design/media/img/dme/all1.png and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! how dumb was I !