# Image error 404 on GitHub Pages

Tags: image, github, http-status-code-404, jekyll, github-pages

My page doesn't want to load the image:
[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGnal.png)

But it's 100% there. Everything works fine on my local machine.
I didn't messed up with branches and paths.

[Github pages setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bnj5.png)

Stackowerflow doesn't allow me to provide more than 2 links yet due to my low reputation, so I'll provide them in comments

Comment: The image is there:
https://github.com/aleksspeaker/multicora/blob/gh-pages/images/Bizkonect.svg

The page is here:
https://aleksspeaker.github.io/multicora/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GET image 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282401/get-image-404-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **HTML** references `bizkonect.svg` but the image is called `Bizonect.svg`. Notice the capital **B**. Either rename the image or use the capital **B** in your **HTML**.

Comment: Omg! That simple!
Thank you so much Carl!

Comment: Carl,
By the way, would you suggest to use lowercase in filenames everywhere?

Alex

Comment: Personally, I would but it doesn't really matter if you reference it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this case and my problem is I set the image path starting '/......' not './....' it works on local but github page.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by reducing my image size. I had an image over 10MB, which does not work on the GitHub free plan.